# Requirejs: pass parameters when using data-main Entry Point

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, model-view-controller, dependency-injection, requirejs

In all my projects I'am using the following approach to handle js throughout the entire app. However, I'am not happy with the way I'am passing variables to the modules inside the js: I declare them on html and blindly use them on the module.

All the stackoverflow questions/answer I found talk about different setup and not using this data-main Entry Point approach.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
    <article class="row m-b-xxl settings" data-js="modules/home"></article>

    <script>
        var bar = 'foo';
    </script>

    <script src="require.js" data-main="main"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'jquery.min',
        'foundation': 'foundation.min'
    },
    shim: {
        "foundation": {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Foundation'
        }
    }
});

// Load our app module 'main.js' and pass it to our definition function
requirejs(['app'], function (App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

**app.js**

```
// The base app
var widgetList = {};

define(['jquery', 'foundation' ], function ($, Foundation) 
      {    
        var initialize = function () {
            // Set user agent
            var doc = document.documentElement;
            doc.setAttribute('data-useragent', navigator.userAgent);

            // Do the widget loading
            $('[data-js]').each(function () {
                var scope = this;

                requirejs([$(scope).data('js')], function (widget) {
                    var widgetDeclaration = new widget();
                    widgetDeclaration.init(scope);
                    widgetList[widgetDeclaration.name] = widgetDeclaration;
                });
            });
        }

        return {
            initialize: initialize
        };
    }
);
```

**modules/home.js**

```
define(['jquery'], function ($) {
    var Widget = function () {
    };
    Widget.prototype = {
        name: 'Dashboard Home',
        init: function (scope) {
            "use strict";                
            console.log(bar);
    };

    return Widget;
});
```

So how to properly pass configuration parameters to the modules?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could find for my problem is by changing my setup of requirejs:

- Include requirejs in header: `<script src="require.js"></script>`
- Put the page config in a module and give it a module_id: `<script type="text/javascript">define('homeConfig', function () {var homeConfig = {};return homeConfig;});</script>`
- Load requirejs config: `<script>requirejs(['main.js'], function () { /*load or init your app here */});</script>`
- Now you have a module named `homeConfig` that you can use iside your other modules :)

So at the end I didn't use the [data-main Entry Point](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#data-main) as it doesn't fit to my setup.